# Clang Exits with Error Code 1

Tags: freebsd, gnu-make, clang

gmake (with Clang10) complains that in file m_file.cpp there is "no matching function for call to 'fileno'".  Also, that it "cannot initialize a param of type 'FILE *' ::fclose(m_fp).

In /usr/include/stdio.h gmake outputs the error "candidate function not viable: cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'struct _IO_FILE *' to 'FILE *' int fileno (FILE *)';

In total, 19 errors get thrown in m_file.cpp (in the app src/mstl directory), stdio.h (in /usr/include), and m_exception.h (also in src/mstl).

At the bottom of gmake's output I get:
[Makefile:76:m_file.o] Error 1
[Makefile:20:all] Error 2

Here's some info about the system I'm working on.  Dell Inspiron 6000, i386 Celeron M. The OS is FreeBSD12.

I know that the compiler might have something to do with these errors (but, I'm not very experienced). Could the fact that I'm building this on an old machine be a factor?  Do you recommend that I downgrade the compiler or upgrade to a bit newer machine?  Just some ideas/suggestions...

While we're at it, could you please explain what all these files with the 'm_' prefix have in common?

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: You'd better post this question with a full error log on some FreeBSD mailing list, like `freebsd-ports`.

Comment: Sounds like it's code that's written specifically for Linux as `_IO_FILE` is a [glibc thing](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h.html#_IO_FILE), I think. Is the code open source and if so can you link to it? You might have some work to do removing Linuxisms from the code before it can be built.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies.  I'll have to read up on glibc. 
 Here is the code: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scidb/files/scidb-beta-code-1475.tgz/download

Comment: Did you modify the project's `configure` script to be able to compile it with `clang`?  It seem as if it _requires_ `gcc` and `g++`. I can see no indication in the project's documentation that it's ported to any other environment than Linux.

Comment: I know someone who compiled it with clang.  As a matter of fact, I was using gcc and when I switched to clang gmake got much farther than gcc - a difference of almost 5 minutes, in fact.  Why do you say that it requires gcc and g++?  This is a line at the very top of Makefile in the project's root directory, "# Makefile for Scidb for Unix operating systems".

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I figured it out.  At first, I wasn't sure whether it was a SO or a Unix&Linux post because I'm compiling/loading a Linux program in a Unix-like OS.  It could be either one.